# Why I can't find Chrome as a debug target?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

[image]

As you can see, there is only `Windows` debug.
I removed `android` and `ios` folders so it is not strange not to see them, but it's strange that I can't see `Chrome`.

Why there is only `Windows (desktop)`? Any way to debug with Chrome (or Edge)?

## flutter doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.675], locale ja-JP)
    • Flutter version 2.10.5 at C:\Flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 5464c5bac7 (4 weeks ago), 2022-04-18 09:55:37 -0700
    • Engine revision 57d3bac3dd
    • Dart version 2.16.2
    • DevTools version 2.9.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\yukik.000\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.11)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2019 version 16.11.32228.343
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[√] VS Code (version 1.67.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\yukik.000\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.40.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64 • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.675]

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Wasn't `[√] Chrome installed` here before?

Comment: your project is web enabled or not? or print the output of `flutter devices` command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run below command if your project is not `web enabled` or not `Web folder` inside your project

```
flutter config --enable-web
```

Then restart **VsCode** and run your project with available device **Chrome** or **Edge**.

Comment: this does not work for Android Studio. Web / Chrome is still not available after restart.

Comment: @Raptor this is working on `VS Code` very well